# Statements are not running sequentially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

When I run the following `searchSessionData` function, the log statements gets printed in the following order - 1,3,4,5,2 instead of 1,2,3,4,5.

*Overview:*

`searchSessionData` basically finds unseen dates range and then using that range it calls the `fetchData` function and then it just prints in the console.

`fetchData` uses the dates and fetches data and pushes all of them to a `dataMap => it is a map` and returns the data back

```
async function searchSessionData(sdate,edate){
    var data;
    // get range
    var unseenDates=getUnseenDates(new Date(sdate),new Date(edate));
    unseenDates.forEach( range => {
         fetchData(range.start,range.end);
    });
    // weave all data
    console.log(3);
    data=[];
    var allDatesinrange= getAllDates(new Date(sdate), new Date(edate));
    console.log(4);
    printElements(allDatesinrange);
    console.log(5);
}

// fetch data from the API and stores it to the hashmap
const fetchData = async(sdate='', edate='')=>{
    try {
        // console.log('fetching...')
        var response;
        var data;

        // send requests to fetch data from api
        console.log(1);
        response = await fetch(`${APOD_url}${api_key}${startDate}${sdate}${endDate}${edate}`)
        currentDataIndex=0;
        data = await response.json();
        //if data is array, enter data to map for each entry
        // console.log(dataMap);
        data.forEach(async element => {
            await dataMap.set(element.date),element);
        });
        console.log(2);

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return 
    }
}
```

Anyone know what the issue is and how can it be solved?
I am not quite sure but I think it could be due to the promises.

Comment: You didn't show enough code to reproduce the problem. In particular `searchSessionData` is never called anywhere (the bug might be at the call site)

Comment: Although the bug is likely [javascript - Using async/await with a forEach loop - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: I see. So **when you call `searchSessionData`** (write this part explicitly!), the logged content is as you written in the question?

Comment: Okay, then the bug is definitely that (and also you miss an `await` for `fetchData` function call)

Comment: @user202729 Yes.. i think you are right... Thanks for linking me to that question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing wrong in two places

1. `fetchData` is an `async` function but you are calling it normally in `searchSessionData`
2. `.forEach` loop doesn't work with `async/await` combo and you're using it in two places.

To fix this and make need to change you two `.forEach` functions like below:

```
for ( range of unseenDates ) {
     await fetchData(range.start,range.end);
};
```

---

```
for ( element of data ) {
    await dataMap.set(element.date),element);
};
```

---

You might even consider using a `await Promise.all` function if the functions in loops don't need to fire in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
    unseenDates.forEach( range => {
         fetchData(range.start,range.end);
    });
```

Try

```
    for (const range of unseenDates) {
         await fetchData(range.start,range.end);
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought for each is the same as for..of just a different syntax... but i was wrong...thanks! :)